# How to remove all the symbols to create a tab delimited file?

Tags: regex

I have a file that contains such sentences:

```
    >Mouse|chr1:52136377-52136981 | element 1 | negative
    >Mouse|chr15:52166424-52166999 | element 2 | negative
```

I want the output to be **tab delimited**  like this:

```
    Mouse   chr1    52136377    52136981    element 1   negative
    Mouse   chr15   52166424    52166966    element 2   negative
```

It's very tricky for me as I'm extremely new to regular expression and sed. I tried using sed to remove all the symbols like `: , | , - , and  >` and insert a tab but it didn't work.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Please post that `sed` attempt.

Comment: `perl -lne 'print join "\t",split/\W+/' file`

Comment: `perl -F\\W+ -le 'print join "\t",@F' file`

Comment: `cat file | tr -s [:punct:] '\t'`

Comment: `tr -s [:punct:] '\t' < file`

Comment: `perl -lpe 's/\W+/\t/g' file`

Answer (score 1):

Extended ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -E 's/ *[>\|:-] */\t/g' file
```

The output:

```
    Mouse   chr1    52136377    52136981    element 1   negative
    Mouse   chr15   52166424    52166999    element 2   negative
```

---

- `[>\|:-]` - character class containing all the crucial characters to replace

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this: `[>|:\- ]+` with a single `\t`...

Comment: OP may have problems using this pattern in `sed` (it is invalid in POSIX).

Comment: Which part is invalid?

Comment: In BRE POSIX, `+` matches a literal `+` and they do not support escaped sequences inside bracket expressions. So, your `-` in the middle of the bracket expression will form an invalid range (both in ERE and BRE).